# Find 3 or more consecutive transaction record where the transaction amount greater than 100 and the records belong to the same category

Tags: sql

I have a customer transaction table which has 3 columns, id, Category, TranAmount. Now I want to find 3 or more consecutive transaction records which belongs to the same category and the TranAmount greater than 100.
Below is the sample table:

```
Id    Category   TranAmount
 1           A          190
 2           A          160
 3           A          169  
 4           B          190
 5           A          90
 6           B          219
 7           B          492
 8           B          129
 9           B          390
 10          B          40
 11          A          110
 12          A          130
```

And the output should be:

```
Id    Category   TranAmount
 1           A          190
 2           A          160
 3           A          169
 6           B          219
 7           B          492
 8           B          129
 9           B          390
```

Comment: Tag with the dbms you are using.  SQL is just a language used by multiple dbms vendor.  Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is a sql test, not from work. So any dbms is fine, I can output all the category which TranAmount > 100 but don't know how to do the consecutive condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into "gaps and islands" reference for a deeper understanding of the approach. Here's one of many you could read: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

In this specific problem you have two conditions that cause a break in a consecutive series, those being a change in category or an amount that doesn't meet the threshold.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (order by Id) as rn,
        row_number() over (partition by
            Category, case when TranAmount >= 100 then 1 else 0 end order by Id) as cn
    from Transactions
), grp as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by rn - cn) as num
    from data
    where TranAmount >= 100
)
select * from grp where num >= 3;
```

https://rextester.com/DUM44618

Comment: The code is awesome, Thanks! The link is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this out yet but give this a try.

```
SELECT Id, Category, Amount FROM Table 
WHERE Amount > 100
and Category IN 
 (SELECT Category FROM Table
  WHERE Amount > 100
  GROUP BY Category HAVING COUNT (Category ) >= 3)
```

Comment: The result will also have id 11 and id 12, because count(category) will count all the category in table.

Comment: @Flyingshrimp thanks just edited it to count amounts > 100.

Comment: still not working. Because count(amounts)>100 will count all the rows, not just the consecutive records with same category. It has the same output as count(category)

Answer (score 0):

This will work if there are no gaps between the ids:

```
select distinct t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select t.id from tablename t 
  where t.tranamount > 100
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where id = t.id - 1 and category = t.category and tranamount > 100
  )
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where id = t.id + 1 and category = t.category and tranamount > 100
  )
) tt on t.id in (tt.id - 1, tt.id, tt.id + 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32a71b2c05363fd327fe434d1e1c72b5).
Results:

```
Id | Category | TranAmount
-: | :------- | ---------:
 1 | A        |        190
 2 | A        |        160
 3 | A        |        169
 6 | B        |        219
 7 | B        |        492
 8 | B        |        129
 9 | B        |        390
```